# Differences between iOS 7 to iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7.1

Just updated my Xcode to 5.1 and the iPhone i work on to the 7.1.0.
A lot of apps that I have made, I have to redesign for the new iOS, because whenever you used a UINavigation bar, the Y point of your UITableView in UITableViewController would be the actual screen coordinate, so you would have to add 64 every time, or `UINavigationBar.size.height`.

Now this is changed, there is no need to add 64, the new 0 point is just after the navigation bar.

Did anyone notice any ether differences?

And does anyone now how will the changes effect the users how **did not** update to 7.1.0?

Comment: A UITableViewController has no Y point; it is not a view. What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: I Edited the question, i was talking about a UITable inside A UITableViewContorller

Comment: But I'm still not seeing any difference. A table view by default still has its 0 point at the top of the screen behind the top of the navigation bar, just as you would expect - unless you turn off edge extending. But that was always true.

Comment: If you will use a XIB and have a table view stretched on all the View, is IOS 7 the origin y point 0 would be above the navigation bar, and now after 7.1 its not, its a fact. try it.  And it has nothing to do with edge extending.

Comment: I did try it. I made a new iPhone project using the Master-Detail template. The table view's 0 point is the 0 point of the screen, at the top of the navigation bar, exactly as before.

Comment: Well i thats strange, I do not know what to say, because i'm right now redesigning two apps that looked perfect, and now are crooked..

Comment: This looks like similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356597/update-to-xcode-5-1-and-layout-for-4-inches-does-not-works-fine

Comment: That doesn't look related to me.

Comment: Yeah, I also created a new one project and create table view. Table view's 0 point is the 0 point of the screen, at the top of the navigation bar, exactly as before, BUT in my app the table has y=64 and stay by 64 px LOWER then NavBar(( Why? Very strange...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and found that including

```
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

helped to resolve my issue.
I noticed that if I brought my tables and data up to the top in the xib file to match how 7.1 handles it...it messed it up for 7.0. Including the code above while having the content at the top of the xib file proved to work for both 7.0 and 7.1.

Hope that helps,

Wes

Comment: I actuality already remade my project lol, but the is a very good answer, Thanks!