# Update to Xcode 5.1 and layout for 4 inches does not works fine

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I have just updated to Xcode 5.1 and when I reopen my project something estrange happened with the **4 inches iPhone**layout.

Now it fits only to 3 inches.

[image: 2 new zones appeared]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the 4-inch device / simulator shows only the 3.5-inch layout, that is a sign that you have forgotten to include a 4-inch launch image in your project. The runtime uses the launch image to decide whether to display at 4 inches on the 4-inch device.